# Flask in docker, access other flask server running locally

Tags: docker, flask, leaflet

After finding a solution for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134064/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-large-geotiffs-on-a-leaflet-map), I have another question: I am running a flask app in a docker container (my web map), and on this map I want to show tiles served by a (flask-based) [Terracotta tile server](https://github.com/DHI-GRAS/terracotta) running in another docker container. The two containers are on the same docker network and can talk to each other, however only the port where my web server is running is open to the public, and I like to keep it that way. Is there a way I can serve my tiles somehow "from local" without opening the port of the tile server? Maybe by setting up some redirects or something?

Main reason for this is that I need someone else to open ports for me, which takes ages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your docker containers on a remote machine like ec2, then you need not worry about a port being open to public, as by default ports are closed in ec2 or similar services. You just need to open the port on which you are running your app, you can use aws console for that.

If you are running your docker container locally or on some server for which you don't have cosole access, then you can use somekind of firewall to open or close a port. I personally prefer [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) for Ubuntu systems. You can allow a certain range of ports using a simple command such as `sudo ufw allow 9000` to allow incoming tcp packets on port 9000. Similarly you can `deny` incoming packets to a port. Also, you can open a port to a certain ip (like your own ip) using `sudo ufw allow from <ip address>`.

Comment: yeah, I am running it on a remote, but my problem is how to serve the tiles for leaflet without opening the port of the tile server...

Comment: Okay let's consider that your app server is running on port 9000 and your tile server is running on port 2000. You should first deny incoming requests to all the ports using `sudo ufw deny` and then open the 9000 port to public using `sudo ufw allow 9000`. This way you tiles server can be accessed only from the remote machine on which it is running. You can refer to ufw documentation for detailed explanation.

Comment: but how should I access my tiles then? In leaflet, which is run in Javascript on the users machine, I can't use http://localhost:2000/tileserver/{x}/{y}/{z}.png, because its not accessible.

Comment: So, you are saying that you want to serve your tiles server on a port and want to access that port from outside the machine using port redirects, but then there is no purpose of closing the port, security will still be compromised. There are only 2 ways you can do this. First is enable authentication for tiles server, or else the leaflet should be running on the same machine as tiles server.